# I have a structural problem with my user management code in django

Tags: django

I'm new to django. I'm trying to make a custom user management in django admin.

I have an admin,py like this.

"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from .forms0 import UserCreationForm, UserAdminChangeForm
from .models import User
#from django.contrib import apps.authentication.models import apps.site.register(model)

## Register your models here.

```
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    search_fields = ['employee', 'username']

    add_form = UserAdminCreationForm
    form = UserAdminChangeForm

    list_display = ('username', 'employee', 'admin', 'staff', 'active')
    list_filter = ('admin', 'staff', 'active')
```

"""

*It calls form0.py first before my model.py*

"""
add_form = UserAdminCreationForm
form = UserAdminChangeForm
"""

Models.py

"""
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager,
PermissionsMixin, UserManager

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name='Username')
    employee = models.OneToOneField('Employee',
                                    null=True,
                                    blank=True,
                                    verbose_name='Employee ID',
                                    related_name='user',
                                    on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

"""

form0.py

"""
from django import forms
from django.db import models
from .models import User

```
class UserAdminCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
    fields, plus a repeated password."""

    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'employee', 'admin', 'active', 'staff', 'groups')
```

"""

*I get this error When I migrate it loads forms0 first before model and I get the following*

**'ValueError: Cannot create form field for 'employee' yet, because its related model 'Employee' has not been loaded yet'**

*I have a conflict if I refer to admin.py. It gives me this error.*

**"ImportError: cannot import name 'employee' from partially initialized module 'apps.main.admin' (most likely due to a circular import)"**

*Please let me know how I can structure my code to avoid this conflict.*

Answer (score 0):

You should use Employee, not the string 'Employee'

```
employee = models.OneToOneField('Employee', /// this shouldn't be string. Try just Employee without ''
                                    null=True,
                                    blank=True,
```